# How to save an Excel file via COM interface in a github actions workflow

Tags: excel, github, github-actions, pywin32, excel-interop

I've got a self-hosted windows runner and I try to run a workflow that executes a python script which creates an Excel file. The .yaml code of the workflow:

```yaml
name: test
run-name: test
on: [push]
jobs:
  create-excel:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Create excel
        run: python create_excel.py
```

The script creates an Excel document via COM interface (usage of COM is compulsory, I cannot switch to pandas / xlrd or other packages):

```python
import os
import win32com.client as win32

excel = win32.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add()
workbook.SaveAs(os.getcwd() + '\\Created.xlsx')
workbook.Close()
excel.Quit()
```

If I run the python script locally everything works fine.
The workflow crashes though: it can create the Excel COM object and a new file, but the COM object then fails to save the File:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\actions-runner\_work\TestRepo\create_excel.py", line 8, in <module>
    workbook.SaveAs(os.getcwd()+'\\Created.xlsx')
  File "<COMObject Add>", line 4, in SaveAs
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'SaveAs method of Workbook class failed', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the solution: you need to change DCOM settings for Excel:

- Press Win+R, type dcomcnfg
- Expand Component Services > My Computer > DCOM Config
- Find Microsoft Excel > Properties (right click) > under the Identity tab set it to "The interactive user for background services".

Answer (score 3):

Tried to reproduce your issue on `windows-latest` (which points to [Windows Server 2022](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/win/Windows2022-Readme.md)) runner but it worked fine.

Apparently, it has something to do with your `self-hosted` runner. After going through other similar threads, I gathered that you might need to verify whether you have the write access to that path or not.

Here's my workflow:

```yaml
name: win_excel_com_test

on: workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  ci:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - name: Install Office
        run: choco install office365business

      - name: Set up script
        env:
          SCRIPT: |
            import os
            import win32com.client as win32

            excel = win32.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
            workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add()
            workbook.SaveAs(os.getcwd() + '\\Created.xlsx')
            workbook.Close()
            excel.Quit()
        run: |
          pip install pywin32
          echo $env:SCRIPT > excel.py
          python --version

      - name: Run script
        run: |
          python excel.py
          ls
```

**Output**:

[image: output]